# Accessing profile septic secret in Springbok from AWS secret manager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

Problem: While booting up a Spring Boot application, I want to access profile specific secrets from AWS secret manager.

Secrets are stored as

`/app/${env}/app-un`
&
`/app/${env}/app-pw`

My spring boot **bootstrap.yml** looks like

```
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    default-context: application
    prefix: /app/dev
    name: app_credential
    profile-separator: _
    fail-fast: true
    enabled: true
```

this works fine for **dev** environment. But I want to make it generic by keeping a place holder for **environment**. like the one given below

`prefix: /app/${env}`

> Note: profile-separator is of little help here as I cannot change the secret name to use <secret_name>_env

Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how you run this but use an env variable to set this is probably the way to go

Comment: yes @grekier , parallely I am checking with the devops engineer for a similar approach.

Comment: This is resolved. I have 'spring.profiles.active' set to every deployment. So using ${spring.profiles.active} will resolve the issue. And there are much better ways of handling the secrets manager mentioned here (https://refactorfirst.com/spring-boot-fetch-secrets-from-aws-secrets-manager) & (https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.0/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-secrets-manager)